# How to refactor generate_boards method to achieve desired output?

Tags: ruby

UPDATE: I have the answer...I'll post it up for all in a few moments...Thanks for your time.

I'm trying to output a hash containing a series of other hashes. I can print to screen on the command line each hash individually but I need them inside a variable and referenced via and index as name value pairs. I've been working on this for days any assist is much appreciated.

P.S. I'm still very noobish in Ruby so if you have a possible answer can you please demonstrate exactly where in the method in question I would need to execute your answer / clue....perhaps via github gist.

Here is the entire module...the problem exist inside the method 'generate_boards'...

https://github.com/thefonso/rubytactoe/blob/minimax_1/lib/TTT_pseudo_code.rb

You can see what I'm passing the method in question in this test...

https://github.com/thefonso/rubytactoe/blob/minimax_1/spec/TTT_pseudo_code_spec.rb

Here is the output I am getting currently...

```
 {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"O", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"X"}
 {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"O", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "}
 {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"O"}
 {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"O"}
```

What I want, should look like this....

```
 boards = {
   :vb01 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"O", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"X"},
   :vb02 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"O", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
   :vb03 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"O"},
   :vb04 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"O"}
 }
```

I've been fighting this thing for days...Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer is this refactored generate_boards method...notice the @virtual_board_hash[@i] = new_board.grid

```
def generate_boards(board, player)
  virtual_board = board.dup
  new_board_hash = {}
  empty_spaces = virtual_board.grid.select{ |k, v| v == " " }.keys

  empty_spaces.each do |space|

    cloned_board = Board.new
    cloned_board.grid = board.grid.clone

    if player == 'O'
      new_board = move_as_somebody(cloned_board, 'X', space)
      new_player = 'X'
       @virtual_board_hash[@i] = new_board.grid
    else
      new_board = move_as_somebody(cloned_board, 'O', space)
      new_player = 'O'
       @virtual_board_hash[@i] = new_board.grid
    end
    generate_boards(new_board, new_player)

  end
  return @virtual_board_hash
end
```

and this move_as_somebody method..notice the @i

```
def move_as_somebody(board, player, empty_space)      
  board.grid[empty_space] = player
  @i+=1
  return board
end
```

but also inside this initialize method....I know, I know...I'm using an initialize method inside a module...why not just call this a class? Well I'm just doing this for the sake of running the test and inside the test I feed this module into a class.

```
def initialize
  @virtual_board_hash = {}
  @count = 0
  @i = 0
end
```

In the actual game code all of this is just called as a module so I'll initialize these variables in a future calling method 'minimax' that will act upon the resulting output hash.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've been looking at your TTT_pseudo_code.rb file a bit, and I have to admit, I'm a little lost in there, right now. For one, I'm confused why you have a module, but you're including an initialize method, inside of which you're setting class instance variables (@@vars). Why not just make a class and be done with it?

But, all that aside, let's just take what you have right now and consider how to transform it into what you want. Presumably, what you have is an array of hashes to begin with. You can use the Ruby Enumerable method inject to transform that array into a hash, like so:

```
array_of_hashes = [
  {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"O", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"X"},
  {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"O", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
  {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"X", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"O"},
  {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"O", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"O"}
]

i = 1
hash_of_hashes = array_of_hashes.inject({}) do |hofh, hash|
  hofh["vb0#{i}".to_sym] = hash
  hofh
end
```

That should give you a hash that transforms what you have into exactly what you asked for in your question above.

Hope that helps.

Dave

Comment: Oh jedi master Dave... "you have a module, but you're including an initialize method, inside of which you're setting class instance variables (@@vars)"...what you are witnessing is the stressed out results of banging my poor head against the desk. Your answer totally helps. I just finished pairing with another coder where I am and I'll post up the answer I have in a sec...and thank you for taking the time. :)